# Как исправить ошибку KeyError u'\u041d'?

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Есть простой блог на Python 2.7, django 1.9. При создании поста на английском языке - все работает. Если создаю пост на русском языке через админку (slug для такого поста там же задаю вручную) - пост на общей странице отображается корректно. Как только пробую посмотреть этот пост отдельно - появляется "Ошибка 500 Internal Server Error". 
В логах прописано -

```
File "/home/dani/blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",             line 732, in resolve
new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
File "./posts/templatetags/urlify.py", line 8, in urlify
return quote_plus(value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1293, in quote_plus
s = quote(s, safe + ' ')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1288, in quote
return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u041d'
```

В начале каждого .py файла прописано

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Вот код самой функции post_detail

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
    context = {
        'title': instance.title,
        'instance': instance,
        'share_string': share_string,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)
```

Хостинг - pythonanywhere.

UPD.
Ошибка исчезла после использования функции urlquote_plus вместо quote_plus. Спасибо @SergeyGornostaev и @Mae

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: Добавил текст ошибки в сам вопрос.

Comment: Ошибка пропала после обновления самой функции urlify.py. Туда тоже добавил urlquote_plus вместо quote_plus. Вернул строчку html кода и все работает. Спасибо. Вопрос тоже обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обрабатывать юникодные символы, используйте документированную функцию `urlquote_plus` вместо `quote_plus`, как написано в [документации](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/unicode.html#uri-and-iri-handling). Тогда вам не нужно будет делать `encode('utf-8')`, как советует @SergeyGornostaev

```
share_string = urlquote_plus(instance.content) // в функции post_detail
```

или

```
return urlquote_plus(value) // в функции urlify
```